# Python copying arrays correctly

Tags: python, arrays

How to copy array correctly? 2 methods give different outputs. I can't understand the logic behind it. What I wanted to achieve was the first one. Remove the repeating ones once the event occurs think it as time series. How is assigning predefined array differs from initializing new one?

```
myarray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
         
duparray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

for i in range(0, len(myarray)):
    if myarray[i] == myarray[i-1] and myarray[i] == 1:
        duparray[i] = 0
        
print(duparray)

OUTPUT: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

```
myarray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
         
duparray = myarray

for i in range(0, len(myarray)):
    if myarray[i] == myarray[i-1] and myarray[i] == 1:
        duparray[i] = 0
        
print(duparray)

OUTPUT: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: `duparray = myarray` isn't creating a copy. It's just a new reference to the same object.

Comment: SIdenote: Everyone referring to arrays here actually refers to lists as Python uses lists by default.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign an array to a new variable, all the changes made on the previous one is transferred to the new one.

One way of doing this is by making a copy of the array.

```
myarray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
         
duparray = myarray.copy()
```

This way, any changes on 'myarray' won't pass to 'duparray'.